# Bootstrap modal window is grayed out

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Go to [this site](http://searchnwork.com/index.php/users), click "Log In" in the top right corner, and a twitter-bootstrap modal window will pop out but be grayed out.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Asking us to visit your website it's not a good practice, as later when we stumble upon an issue like this there's no way we can see the issue you had

Comment: Check for instances where Modal is accidentally Model.  This was the case for me.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's because `.navbar-fixed-top` has a z-index of 1030 while the modal backdrop has a z-index of 1040, causing the modal to overlay the navbar.

To fix this, just adjust the `.modal-backdrop` z-index value to be lower than 1030 - e.g.

```
.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 1020;
}
```

Comment: not working for BS4

Comment: below works in bs4

.modal-backdrop {
    display: none;
}

.modal {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

Answer (score 29):

You can also use:

```
 .modal-backdrop.in { z-index: auto;}
```

Comment: this is the best answer.

Comment: No, not at all - don't work on BT4.1xx.

Answer (score 28):

First of all, add **data-backdrop="false"** to your modal div

Then add the following to your style:

```
.modal { background: rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.8); min-height:1000000px; }
```

Don't forget to add the close button into your modal...

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
```

Cheers..

Comment: This worked in my case where I was using bootstrap them selector... switching to a theme and then back to the default would cause a modal on my page to be grayed out. Now it works correctly with data-backdrop="false"

Comment: Thanks; adding `data-backdrop="false"` fixed it right away.

Comment: Thank you sir. My issue was only in IE, but this fixed me up good. I did have to set the z-index of my nav to -1 to get it to lay underneath. Cheers.

Comment: This worked for me while the two other solutions involving z-index did not. I would like to understand why. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: NOTE: Copying the Example from Bootstrap works without the data-backdrop="false" Attribute, somehow when I add my own (dynamic) id's to button, div and modal-head, it is not working. Also beginning the id with an INT (does not matter if you put as string or as int) is not working at all, the modal is not showing up.

Answer (score 2):

I had to add !important to get it working.

```
.modal-backdrop {
    z-index: 1020!important;
}
```